# What's going on with these objects?

Tags: mesh, objects, viewlayers

This is a 3rd-party Wavefront OBJ (a spaceship) I imported into Blender. The object appears to be composed of hundreds of individually-named entities visible in the View Layer, each with a material icon. I haven't seen this before; anybody know what's going on?

I think the source file is probably at least 20 years old and maybe came from a native Lightwave object. I tried importing this OBJ into other apps, but they report the file as being corrupt; Blender is the only app that will import it.

The OBJ appears to be salvageable, but I'm not understanding what's going on. Any ideas? Thanks. Blender 2.93.6 Windows 10

[image]

Comment: Those appear to be only materials, assigned to object "Mars 2' mesh '3'.  There are probably different materials assigned to different face sets (vertex Groups).  If you put the object into EDIT MODE,  Deselect all, and then select the Materials Tab.   If you then select a Material Name and click on the Select button beneath,  it'll highlight the Faces or Vertices that this material is assigned.   You can also select the Object Data Properties tab, and view Vertex Groups, you'll probably be able to select a group, and then click on the Select button beneath to show that grouping also.

Comment: Also, If when you render you don't see anything but some gray material, then you did not import the actual material itself, and you could clean up (remove) all of these materials.

Answer (score 1):

These are not objects, they are materials assigned to your object.

You should be able to see the same list in the `Properties Editor` > `Materials` > Materials slot list.

In edit mode, you can select a material in the list, and click the `Select` button in order to select the mesh parts assigned to that slot.

This is usually important to keep these as is if you don't want to lose the object's materials. But sometimes, some importers create a lot of duplicates. Or mistakenly convert mesh layers from CAD softwares into material slots or vertex groups into Blender. If you don't have a use for them, you can remove the material slots one by one using the `-` button on the side of the material slots list.

Comment: Thank you for your responses everyone! I think I understand, and this gives me the confidence to invest more time in this file.

Answer (score 1):

This has been answered correctly already, but just wanted to say I had this laying about as well.
It dates from around 2014 and does indeed appear to be a natively Lightwave object:

[image]

And those are indeed surface (material) names with textures allocated to each one.

The actual object is made of many layers, which are unnamed.

There are no vertex groups assigned and one generic uv map that seems unassigned.

[image: srsfsdf]

hth